# What value will contain_of() return when two different integers are considered in a structure

Tags: struct, macros

Consider we defined a structure T

```
struct T {
int a, b;
};
```

if the address of b is 0x8b3000c and sizeof(int) is 4. what value will `container_of()` return when invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`container_of` is a macro in linux kernel code, which calculates address of container.

For ewxample, in your case

```
struct T {
    int a, b;
};
```

Applying `container_of` on address of `b` will yield address of `struct T`

```
struct T *pT = container_of(ptr_b, struct T, b);
```

where `ptr_b` will hold the address of b, `&b`

Normally, we won't care the physical value we got, like `0x8b3000c`, as we work with identifiers.

As you are interested in physical, as both members are `int` with size 4, ignoring padding,  pT will have `(Ox8b3000c -4) = Ox8b30008`

**BUT BUT, Please never make such assumption while coding**, struct may be padded. It is always good to use `sizeof`

Comment: Sorry for being noob.
I want to understand this. Could you please clarify. So you mean the address (some value) of struct T will be returned? so approximately how would this address of struct T look like?

Comment: Please see this, you will understand http://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/

Comment: So the return value here will be Ox8b30008? what is pT here? Thanks!

Comment: Pointer to T which will be the starting location of the struct

Comment: I'm still confused. whre did you get this "Ox8b3000c" from? I mentioned the address of b as 0x8b3000c..

Comment: You have given this as address of `b` in your question